# How can I vertically align <ruby> element with regular text

Tags: html, vertical-alignment

Is there a way to vertically align `<ruby>` element with the bottom of regular text ?

Here are my css & code:

```
body {
  font-family:"Times New Roman";
  }
ruby {
  font-family:"Times New Roman";
    display: inline-flex;
    flex-direction: column-reverse ;
    align-items: center;
  }
rt {
  font-family:"Arial Narrow";
  }
```

```
Mat 1:1 <RUBY><ruby><ruby>Βίβλος<rt>βίβλος</rt></ruby><rt>[The] book</rt></ruby><rt>N-NSF</rt></RUBY> <RUBY><ruby><ruby>γενέσεως<rt>γένεσις</rt></ruby><rt>of [the] genealogy</rt></ruby><rt>N-GSF</rt></RUBY> <RUBY><ruby><ruby>Ἰησοῦ<rt>Ἰησοῦς</rt></ruby><rt>of Jesus</rt></ruby><rt>N-GSM</rt></RUBY> <RUBY><ruby><ruby>Χριστοῦ<rt>Χριστός</rt></ruby><rt>Christ</rt></ruby><rt>N-GSM</rt></RUBY>
```

The result:
[not-wkring](https://i.stack.imgur.com/POkb2.png)

p.s. I've tried `display: inline-block`, but then the vertical order of `<ruby>` element is out-of place.[not working2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j4Agc.png)

p.p.s. `display: inline-flex; flex-direction: column ;` not working as well, see [not working3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xZoxe.png)

Comment: FYI: I've removed the `ruby` tag from your question because it is for the [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/) programming language, not the `<ruby>` HTML element.